# identifier of an instance of com.mess.MessBuddy.entities.ClientEntity was altered from MBA00005 to MBA00001

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, microservices

I'm trying to addImage in my ClientEntity table by there ClientId but i'm getting identifier of an instance of com.mess.MessBuddy.entities.ClientEntity was altered from MBA00005 to MBA00001 error .

This is the code.

```
public class ClientEntity {

    @Id
    private String clientId;
    private String password;
    private String clientName;
    private String area;
    private String taluka;
    private String district;
    private String state;
    private String pinCode;
    private String contactNo1;
    private String contactNo2;
    private String email;
    private Date joiningDate;
    @CreationTimestamp
    private Timestamp createdTs;
    @CreationTimestamp
    private Timestamp updatedTs;
    @Lob
    @Column(columnDefinition = "LONGBLOB")
    private byte[] profileImage;


@RequestMapping("/Client")
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000")
public class ClientController {

    @Autowired
    public ClientService clientService;
    
    @Autowired
    private MemberService memberService;

    @Autowired
    private ClientMemberConnectionService clientMemberConnectionService;

    
    @PostMapping("/register")
    public ResponseEntity<ClientEntity> addClient(@RequestBody ClientEntity client) {
        ClientEntity savedClient = clientService.saveClient(client);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(savedClient, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

@PostMapping("/addImage/{clientId}")
    public ResponseEntity<ClientEntity> addImage(@PathVariable String clientId,@RequestParam ("image") MultipartFile file)
    {
       try {
           if (file.isEmpty()) {
                return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(null);
            }
           System.out.println("ClientId: " + clientId);
           ClientEntity clientEntity = clientService.getClientByClientId(clientId);
           if (clientEntity == null) {
               return ResponseEntity.notFound().build(); 
           }
           System.out.println("ClientEntity before setting profile image: " + clientEntity);
           
            clientEntity.setProfileImage(file.getBytes());
        
            ClientEntity savedClient = clientService.saveClient(clientEntity);
            System.out.println("Saved ClientEntity after saving: " + savedClient);
            return ResponseEntity.ok(savedClient);
        } catch (IOException e) {
        
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body(null);
        }
    }



 @Service
public class ClientServiceImpl implements ClientService {
    
    private static final String PREFIX = "MBA";
    private static int counter = 1;

    @Autowired
    private ClientRepository clientRepository;

    @Autowired
    private ClientMemberConnectionService clientMemberConnectionService;
    
    @Autowired
    private MonthlyDurationDataService monthlyDurationDataService;
    
    @Autowired
    private PaymentTransactionService paymentTransactionService;
    
    @Autowired
        private PasswordEncoder encoder;
    
    public ClientEntity saveClient(ClientEntity clientEntity) {
        String uniqueId = generateUniqueClientId();
        clientEntity.setClientId(uniqueId);
        clientEntity.setPassword(encoder.encode(clientEntity.getPassword()));
        return clientRepository.save(clientEntity);

    }
    @Override
    public ClientEntity getClientByClientId(String clientId) {
        return clientRepository.findByClientId(clientId);
    }
        

        @Override
        public ClientEntity getClientById(String clientId) {
        return clientRepository.findByClientId(clientId);
        }


     private String generateUniqueClientId() {
        String formattedCounter;
        String uniqueId;
        do {
            formattedCounter = new DecimalFormat("00000").format(counter++);
            uniqueId = PREFIX + formattedCounter;
            
        } while (clientRepository.existsByClientId(uniqueId));

        return uniqueId;
}



        public interface ClientService {
    public ClientEntity getClientById(String clientId);
    public ClientEntity saveClient(ClientEntity client);
    boolean doesClientExistByEmail(String email);
    public ClientEntity getClientByEmail(String email);
    public ClientDashBoard getClientDashBoardData(String clientId);
    public ClientEntity getClientByClientId(String  clientId);//clientid
}


    @Repository
    public interface ClientRepository extends JpaRepository<ClientEntity,String> {
        public ClientEntity findByClientId(String clientId);
        public boolean existsByClientId(String clientId);
        public boolean existsByEmail(String email);
        public ClientEntity findByEmail(String email);
    
    
    }
```

I tried creating different method for finding clientID but i did'nt work ,

I want to save Image through addImage API in my existing client by his clientID

Comment: Anyone there to help?